# Dot Product of Two 2-D Column Vectors Using Numpy (Without Transpose)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dot-product

I am trying to calculate dot product of two 2D vectors using numpy
Here is what I know so far:

1. If we have two 1D np arrays like v and w, we can use `np.inner(v, w)` to get the dot product of these two vectors but since 1D arrays have shape of (m, ) I don't like to use them due to making troubles by that lost second dimension in (m, )
2. If we use 2D arrays to define v and w like below:

```
    v = np.array([[1], [3], [5]])
    w = np.array([[2], [4], [6]])
```

We can calculate the dot product by transposing one of these vectors and then using matrix multiplication:

```
    vdotw = v.T @ w
```

or:

```
   vdotw = w.T @ v
```

My question is that **is there any method is numpy that specifically calculate dot product of two vectors (defined as 2D arrays not those funny 1D arrays) directly and without transposing one of them?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Numpy's [`einsum()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) can be used to do this.

However, your request is very unusual. Why don't you want to use transpose? The transpose operator has virtually zero cost: it does not make a copy of the underlying data as I suspect you imagine it to.

Comment: Thank you dshin. I got it completely. I was just curious if there is some function specific for dot product of two 2D vectors in numpy. We should use transpose ...